# Jenkins cron schedule Invalid trigger type "parameterizedCron"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to run only Stage C in pipeline every night based on the parameters. But pipeline is throwing me Invalid trigger type "parameterizedCron" error. Below is my pipeline script. Please help what could be the issue. Also my pipeline is not triggering via cron job i need to trigger manually.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
  }

parameters {
    choice(
            name: 'ENV',
            choices: [ 'uat', 'perf' ],
    )
    booleanParam(
        name: 'RUN',
        defaultValue: true
    )       
}

triggers {
    parameterizedCron('''
        17 14 * * * %RUN=true;ENV=uat
    ''')
}

stages {

    stage ('A') {

    }

    stage ('B') {

    }
    stage('C') {
          when {
            expression { env.RUN || env.ENV == 'uat' }
          }
    ## RUN THIS STAGE

}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you installed and enabled the plugin?

[image]

If you freshly installed the plugin try restarting Jenkins.

Comment: Nope..I did realized after creating this question. Thanks for suggestion.